# JQuery click function not working first time - requires 2 clicks before it functions properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my first question on Stack Overflow so i hope i get a good response!

Basically, i am currently learning the ropes in Javascript and I've just began learning JQuery, I decided to add some JQuery code to make the surrounding div box around a cancel button disappear after clicking. I've managed to successfully/ish do this, however its not responsive first time round upon clicking.

After googling it, i think its because the code first time round only activates the click event to be used. I've spent a fair few hours fiddling and trying to find the right amendment however no luck so far.

Hopefully somebody can help!

**Javascript to create the cancel button:**

```
var cancel = document.createElement("button");
var canceltext = document.createTextNode("Cancel")
activetradediv.appendChild(cancel);
cancel.appendChild(canceltext);
cancel.setAttribute("class","activetradecancel")
cancel.setAttribute("onclick","cancelactivetrade()")
```

**JQuery to action the cancel button**

```
function cancelactivetrade (){
    if (window.confirm("Are you sure you want to cancel this trade? \nClick 'Okay' to confirm"))
    {$('.activetradecancel').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent('.activetradediv').remove();
  });};}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well this is my first answer, so I hope I will be able to help!

Your code behaves like this : 
the first click on the cancel button calls `cancelactivetrade()` which calls a confirm popup. If you click ok in the popup, you then set up a second click event listener. But you have to click a second time to trigger the new click event listener that removes your div.

I would suggest something like this instead :

```
$('.activetradecancel').on('click', function() {
  if (window.confirm("Are you sure you want to cancel this trade? \nClick 'Okay' to confirm"))
  {
    $(this).parent('.activetradediv').remove();
  }
});
```

And you also remove the first event listener `cancel.setAttribute("onclick","cancelactivetrade()")` from your javascript since the [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) takes care of the event listener on its own.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you have nested your click event handlers. The first one runs `cancelactivetrade()` and assigns the `on('click')` handler. The second on runs `cancelactivetrade()` again and assigns another click handler, and then runs the `on()` logic from the previous click.

To fix this you can bind the `on()` event handler directly to the element, so you can use the `this` reference. As you're already using jQuery you can use that to simplify the element creation and appending to the DOM:

```js
$('<button class="activetradecancel">Cancel</button').appendTo(cancel).on('click', function() {
  if (window.confirm("Are you sure you want to cancel this trade? \nClick 'Okay' to confirm")) {
    $(this).parent('.activetradediv').remove();
  };
});
```

Alternatively you can use a single delegated event handler for all the `.activetradecancel` buttons you create:

```js
// call this ONCE when the page loads:
$(document).on('click', '.activetradecancel', function() {
  if (window.confirm("Are you sure you want to cancel this trade? \nClick 'Okay' to confirm")) {
    $(this).parent('.activetradediv').remove();
  };
});

// execute this statement every time you want to create a new button:
$('<button class="activetradecancel">Cancel</button').appendTo(cancel)
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks, this worked :) took a bit of messing around but i managed to get it functioning properly! thankyou